# A name for a linear map from primary to dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Is there a standard name for a linear function $f:\mathbb R^n\to(\mathbb R^n)^*$ defined on the standard basis $e_i, i=1,\dotsc, n,$ of $\mathbb R^n$ by $f(e_i)=e^i$, where $e^i, i=1,\dotsc,n,$ is the standard basis of the dual space $(\mathbb R^n)^*$? If not, what name would be appropriate? I'd like to call it an identity of some sort but it's not really an identity function like, say, $f(x)=x$ would be.

The map $f$ can be extended to $f:\bigwedge\mathbb R^n\to\bigwedge (\mathbb R^n)^*$, where $\bigwedge\mathbb R^n$ is the exterior algebra of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\bigwedge (\mathbb R^n)^*$ is the exterior algebra of the dual space $(\mathbb R^n)^*$, by declaring $f(a\wedge b)=f(a)\wedge f(b)$ for any $a,b\in\bigwedge\mathbb R^n$, e.g. $f(e_1\wedge e_2)=e^1\wedge e^2$. Does this extended $f$ have a name?

Comment: As this is connected with Riesz theorem, it might be appropriate to call it Reisz transformation, or something like that. Ronan calls it Riesz map in Advanced Linear Algebra.